# Placing image over a element to represent it is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to represent that the user selected a option when clicking some element.

I have a grid of small balls like that:

```
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
. . . .
```

I used **divs with border-radius** to represent each ball and tried to add a background image when they have a class `.active`(added via JS) on them. But the image is cutted by the div, so I need another way.

I structured the grid like this: 1 grid > (row >(balls) * 4) * 4). Originally I have 5 rows and 10 balls per row. Adjusted the values to match the example here.

The problem is that when the ball is selected it should show one image bigger than div and increasing the size of the ball is not a option for me **I want to find a better approach to this problem**

```
before == . -- AFTER CLICK --> X(custom image over the ball)
```

How should I do this in a simplistic way ? Using JS and CSS, everything is an option. Since the action is reversible(toggable) I need a way to remove also.

**Tl;Dr**

How to show that a ball is selected by putting an image(any html element or CSS trick would do) over this ball when clicked.

Fiddle of an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/f25nLw3k/

Fiddle with answer:

https://jsfiddle.net/f25nLw3k/2/ thanks to @Omer

Comment: Wouldn't you just be toggling a css class? http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisStanyon/4r5vg/

Comment: You say that increasing the size of the divs isn't an option, but why is that? Can't you give a negative margin to the divs and increase the size so that they take up the same space?

Comment: Please add some code in order to get a positive answer to your problem.

Comment: @MannfromReno toggling is not enough IMO, I tried that but changing the css was not enough since I need that image and it is bigger.

Comment: @jperezo I believe you are right, maybe some wrapper of the size of my image and add the ball inside of it would work. The size of the div can't change because I was actually trying to say about the size of the ball, that it is my div with border-radius that can't change. I will update the question.

Comment: @Henrique M. I will make a fiddle in a minute

Comment: @HenriqueM. I Added the fiddle and used a image from placelholder.it to add a image bigger than the div(ball). You can see on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think i have solution with in your same code.

I just added two lines in your JS and write some scss to make the ball div `position: relative`

```
$('.ball.active').on('click', function(e) {
    var node = $(e.target);
    node.removeClass('active');
    node.find('.bigger-ball').remove();
})

$('.ball').on('click', function(e) {
    var node = $(e.target);

  $('.ball.active').each(function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.bigger-ball').remove();
  });


  node.addClass('active');
  node.append('<span class="bigger-ball"></span>');
});
```

Here's the JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/omerblink/f25nLw3k/3/

You can replace the `<span class="bigger-ball"></span>` with the `<img>` :)

Comment: Thanks, that's the correct idea, I changed your fiddle to be able to toggle the ball. If you could, check here and update the answer please. https://jsfiddle.net/f25nLw3k/2/

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :) Answer and fiddle updated

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using background images. If the image is too big, you can set `background-size: cover;`

The jQuery:

```
// If you click on a cell
$('.column').click(function() {
    // Remove the active class from all cells
    $('.column').removeClass('active');
    // Give this cell the active class
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

The CSS:

```
.column {
  background-image: url('default.png');
  background-size: cover;
}

.column.active {
  background-image: url('active.png');
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/na7pehLn/3/

Comment: I don't want change one background image for another, but placing one image over a div. The balls are made with div and border-radius as I said in the question. This works when I have two images.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using CSS and Javascript.

Simply toggle the `active` class of each `ball`. Define the `ball`s to have a margin and the `active` `ball`s not to.

```
.ball {
    margin: 10px;
    width:1px;
    background: black;
}

.ball.active {
    margin: 0;
    width: 11px;
    background: url(/path/to/img);
}
```

Comment: I can't change the width of the ball. They must stay the same size before and after selected. Only the image that should be over them would be bigger so it will looks like the user selected that specific ball.